# how to make a lambda function work behind ALB as a target?

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, aws-serverless, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a lambda function (python 3.7) behind an ALB. This function accepts 2 parms (length abd bredth) to calculate the area of a rectangle. In a normal scenario,  lamda will get these values from event( event['length'], event['bredth']) and we can test this by sending parms as {"length": 5,"bredth": 10} from console.

Now, when I'm putting this lambda function behind the ALB ( path as /example1) as a target, how to pass these parms to the lambda function? I tried "area = event['multiValueQueryStringParameters']['length'] * event['multiValueQueryStringParameters']['bredth']", but did NOT work. When I'm hitting the endpoint as https://example.com/example1?length=10&bredth=10, it's throwing 502. If I hardcode the value of the area inside the function and hit the endpoint as https://example.com/example1, this works fine and returns the response as json string. Below is the code. Also, in this kind of scenarios, how to test the lambda from console?

```
import json
  def lambda_handler(event, context):    response = {    "statusCode": 200,    "statusDescription": "200 OK",       "isBase64Encoded": False,    "headers": {    "Content-Type":    "text/json; charset=utf-8"    }
   }    #area = event['length'] * event['bredth']    area = event['multiValueQueryStringParameters']['length'] *    event['multiValueQueryStringParameters']['bredth']    #area = 50       response['body'] = json.dumps({"area of the rectangle is": area})
  return response
```

Comment: Start by logging the entire `event` object so you can see exactly how your parameters are being passed in.

Comment: thanks @MarkB! It seems the lambda function was throwing error for wrong datatype. I changed to "int" and it works! code is in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was coming due to improper datatype. Once corrected, it works fine!
Below is the complete code (with the commented code for debugging)

```
import json

def lambda_handler(event, context):
response = {
"statusCode": 200,
"statusDescription": "200 OK",
"isBase64Encoded": False,
"headers": {
"Content-Type": "json; charset=utf-8"
}
     }

keydata1 = int(event['queryStringParameters']['length'])
keydata2 = int(event['queryStringParameters']['bredth'])
area = int(keydata1 * keydata2)
if event['httpMethod']=='GET':
    #response['body'] = json.dumps(event) # I'm just printing the request body as the whole event
    #response['body'] = "this is from GET" # this also works as text in the response
    #response['body'] = json.dumps({"area of the circle is": "this response is json formatted"}) # this also works as json output
    #response['body'] = json.dumps({"area of the circle is": 50}) # this also works as json output
    #response['body'] = json.dumps({"area of the circle is": keydata2}) # this also works as json output
    response['body'] = json.dumps({"area of the circle is": area})
else:
    response['body'] = json.dumps(event)
#response['body'] = json.dumps(event)

return response
```

and here is how I'm invoking my lambda function behind the ALB:

GET example.com/example1?length=50&bredth=25